# The @2x image is not loaded on iPad retina

Tags: ios, ipad

i've been writing an app for iPad. I used 2 images, menuBar.png and menuBar@2x.png, on for normal and the other for retina. When i run on simulator, it's perfect. But when i built and run on iPad 3, it seems doesn't load the retina image. 
Can anyone give me a solution or show me where i go wrong?

Comment: Check that the file names are exactly the same, including case, except for `@2x` (which should be a lower-case `x`)—often, the cause of differing behavior between the simulator and a device is that the simulator uses your local filesystem, which is most likely case-insensitive, but many (all?) iOS devices use a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: i've already checked.They're menuBar@2x.png and menuBar.png

Answer (score 7):

The image should be called:

iPhone non-retina: menuBar.png

iPhone retina:  menuBar@2x.png

iPad non-retina:  menuBar~ipad.png

iPad retina:  menuBar@2x~ipad.png

if not named liked this, it will fall back to the iPhone non-retina image

Comment: i've a lot of view use image like that . But just one that menubar image is go wrong